# Voice call connection routing React-Native

Tags: react-native, routes, connection, twilio

I am trying to build an application which works this way: I as a user want to start a call with another user. The way I want the connection be made is by random. So it will connect to one of the many clients out there by random. Also when other clients try to make a call, it should connect to another random client and so on. I want those phone calls be made via application(such as WhatsApp) not as a phone call.
Now, the question is; is Twilio a good approach for this purpose?
If yes can you tell me which of their feature would fit my app the best?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: How did you implemented the feature of random calling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I can answer that Twilio would be a good approach for you to do this within your own application. I'd recommend using [Twilio Video](http://twilio.com/video) to build this as it allows cross platform communication via audio or video (in your case, you may not need the video, but this will give you the best audio quality).

As an example, my colleague Dominik built a [video roulette application](https://github.com/dkundel/twilio-roulette). It is the case that the interface was built in JavaScript for the web, but the idea would be the same for a native app. The [code for the server side](https://github.com/dkundel/twilio-roulette/blob/master/index.js) part of the application should give some insight into how to connect random pairings.

It's also possible to integrate Twilio Video with CallKit and Connection Services so that you can make outbound calls to other devices that ring like a real incoming call.

Comment: thanks for your response! So in my client part(react-native code) I should create a connection with server-Twilio and then the server will take care of with which client it should connect. I dont want to ring, I want to connect to another client who is trying to connect by random. Can you confirm this is a right logic and if you have any suggestions please let me now!

Comment: btw I want to build this app on React-Native which is a framework for building cross-platform apps. I cannot read anywhere in their documentation that they support React-Native.

Comment: I would recommend you build a server side component for matching users, yes. This has to be your logic though, nothing to do with Twilio. If you want to work with Twilio Video and React Native, I'd take a look at this project: https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc

Comment: Any idea if I can use this library for voice chat (without video)? And if you recommend me create my own server side component, can I use RabbitMQ? If not, what else should I try?

Comment: I would assume you can use the library for just voice, but I've not worked with it myself. As for the server, I recommend building it in whatever language you feel comfortable in.

Comment: I dont really get how this library would be routing multiple calls and connections of clients at the same time?

Comment: That library would allow you to handle the on device stuff in React Native. It wouldn't help with the server side handling for multiple calls, you'll need to write that yourself.